# Как привязать цену доллара к калькулятору в PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день!
Подскажите, возможно ли реализовать такой функционал.
Есть сайт биржи [Клик!](http://www.kase.kz/ru/cur)
На этой страничке есть курс доллара(выделен в прямоугольник)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Возможно ли как-то привязать этот курс к сайту? На сайте будет автоматически подсчитываться сумма сделки, в нашей стране нельзя указывать суммы в долларах.
Для определенных видов услуг цена зафиксирована в долларах и нужно провести расчет суммы исходя из курса с сайта.
Как это можно реализовать?
Спасибо!

Comment: Можно использовать SimpleHTMLDom и распарсить таблицу к себе на сайт, достать оттуда нужные данные и использовать где угодно для расчетов

Answer (score 3):

Если у сайта нет собственного `api` предоставляющего такую возможность, то остается только парсить страницу, а за тем разбирать полученные данные. Сделать это можно с помощью [curl](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php). Функция ниже в качестве аргумента получает ссылку на страницу, и возвращает данные страницы в виде `HTML` разметки. Стоит помнить, что `curl` - это библиотека и ее нужно [подключать](http://php.net/manual/ru/curl.installation.php).

```
function curl_get ($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Опции ниже нужны для того, что бы сервер, к которому делается запрос, считал, что это запрос от настоящего пользователя
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; en-US; SM-G531H Build/LMY48B) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 UCBrowser/11.1.0.882 U3/0.8.0 Mobile Safari/534.30');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Далее нужно достать именно ту цифру, которая Вам нужна. Сделать это можно при помощи [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Библиотека для `php`, которая создает `php` объект из `HTML DOM`. Работает подобно `jQuery` в `Java Script`. Функция ниже принимает в качестве аргументов ссылку на страницу, и селектор(например `'.header-text'`). Так же эта функция использует функцию выше, что бы получить `HTML` разметку.

```
function get_elements($url, $selector){
    // Получаем HTML
    $html = curl_get($url);
    // Создаем объект DOM дерева. Функция из библиотеки simple html dom
    $dom = str_get_html($html);
    // Ищем селектор среди разметки, содержимое которого Вам нужно
    $elements = $dom->find($selector);

    return $elements;
}
```

Стоит предупредить, что если Вы будете слишком часто отправлять запросы, то сервер скорее всего Вас заблокирует, так как Вы создадите лишнюю нагрузку на него

Answer (score 1):

Это частая задача. Есть кстати много открытых API с курсом валют, чтобы не парсить, [пример](http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp). Стабильная реализация задачи сводится к следущему:

1. Создаётся робот, который получает сводки раз в 10 минут.
2. Он их записывает в БД таблицу в виде: дата, валюта, курс. При чём надо проверять отклонения при записи - и в случае чего игнорить запись: защита от глюков апи/робота, чтобы не проводить случайно клиентов по нулевым транзакциям.
3. Затем в коде вашего приложения текущий курс берётся из последней записи этой таблицы.
4. История курса валют пригодится затем при точных расчётах (чтобы узнать - правильно ли посчитана сумма клиенту, для бухгалтерии ). Хранить 144 записи в день, это совсем немного.

Comment: Мне просто стало интересно, а как создаются такие "роботы"?))

Comment: @AtCliff_ в текстовом редакторе, или IDE создаётся скрипт, который ломится в API, получает данные, и записывает их в БД. Скрипт ставится в планировщик (встроенный crontab или планировщик windows в зависимости от ОС) . Больше нечего добавить.